# Access parent form validation in child component Angular 5 control value accessor

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, ngmodel, controlvalueaccessor

I referred this link : http://tylerscode.com/2017/03/splitting-angular-forms-controlvalueaccessor/#respond

I want to validate all fields in child component with control value accessor and template driven forms.

(This is link of issues on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzioet)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Helpful feedback: I requested that you refrain from begging [on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52380202/472495), and since this question also contained begging, I have downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ControlContainer**

> A base class for directives that contain multiple registered instances
>   of NgControl. Only used by the forms module

Use [viewProviders](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#viewProviders) inside your child form

```
 viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cncupd